# How to calculate the aspect ration from a floating point number

Tags: c#

I am given a floating number such as 1.77720212936401 and I want to be able to calculate roughly what the aspect ratio is as a width:height string with width and height being small natural numbers.

JD

///

I have come up with this, currently testing to see if it covers all areas:

```
    static public string Ratio(float f)
    {
        bool carryon = true;
        int index = 0;
        double roundedUpValue = 0;
        while (carryon)
        {
            index++;
            float upper = index*f;

            roundedUpValue = Math.Ceiling(upper);

            if (roundedUpValue - upper <= (double) 0.1)
            {
                carryon = false;
            }
        }

        return roundedUpValue + ":" + index;
    }
```

Comment: You Sir, want the impossible!

Comment: *In mathematics, a ratio expresses the magnitude of quantities relative to each other.* - so you are gonna need one more number.

Comment: @Mitch: Actually, this can be done pretty easily by computing “best rational approximations” with methods such as continued fractions, but I doubt that's what the OP wants :-)

Comment: I think this should not be closed. The problem is very real and there are actual solutions (that are widely used in video players and other software).

Comment: Voting to reopen, but the OP might still consider adding some more detail on the problem he is trying to solve.

Comment: this is a real question with a real solution. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try multiplying it by small integers in a loop and check if the result is close to an integer.

```
double ar = 1.7777773452;
for (int n = 1; n < 20; ++n) {
    int m = (int)(ar * n + 0.5); // Mathematical rounding
    if (fabs(ar - (double)m/n) < 0.01) { /* The ratio is m:n */ }
}
```

Comment: Okay, above method I gave seems to be fine. Checking Tronic's answer.

Comment: Why are you using the 20 value factor? Is it an arbitrary value?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image)), use pre-defined values and estimate the nearest ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is 1.777:1 but it is very difficult to be definitive when you tell us so little.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the actual input is not a floating point number, but you have **width**, **height** and you get the floating point number by dividing them.

In such a case, the problem can be reduced to finding the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor):

```
private static int greatestCommonDivisor(int a, int b) {
    return (b == 0) ? a : greatestCommonDivisor(b, a % b);
}

private static String aspectRatio(int width, int height) {
    int gcd = greatestCommonDivisor(width, height);

    if (width > height) {
        return String.Format("{0} / {1}", width / gcd, height / gcd);
    } else {
        return String.Format("{0} / {1}", height / gcd, width / gcd);
    }
}
```